# Different layers depending on whether the user prints color or monochrome

Tags: color, printing, layers

I have a bar chart in my document that is much clearer with colors. However, my publisher prints backorders in monochrome. I can make a version using different patterns to fill in the bars, but I would like the digital version to still use colors. Is it possible to produce a PDF with different versions of the same graph that are selected *automatically* depending on whether the document is printed in color or monochrome?

I know that I could use OCG layers to allow the user to switch between two versions of a graph. With the ocg-p `printocg=ifvisible` option I could then print the one that is currently selected. However, I am really looking for a solution that makes the decision automatically depending on the printing settings.

The bar chart is made with pgfplots and I'm using XeLaTeX, but I think this is irrelevant. Ideally the solution would be something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ifprintedmonochrome{This text is printed in monochrome.}{This text is printed in color.}

\end{document}
```